# Convert a number of the datatyp String to char

Tags: java, arrays, char

I try to convert numbers of a String in to an array with the datatyp char. My problem is, that the number in my array is everytime 48 to high. I also know that the problem has something to do with ASCII table. What can i do to solve this problem?

```
package Test;

public class Main {




    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int iNumber = 0;    int indexNumber = 0;


        String calculation = "5+8";
        int lengthCalculation = calculation.length();
        int[] number= new int[lengthCalculation/2+1];


        while(iNumber < lengthCalculation) {

            number[indexNumber] = calculation.charAt(iNumber);;

                iNumber+=2;
                indexNumber++;
        }

        for(int q : number) {
            System.out.println(q);         }
    }


}
```

Comment: Please share your expected and actual outputs.

Comment: Your code is not great. What problem are you actually trying to solve? Either, split on `+` (or perhaps on non-digits) and then parse the values. Or, use `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression for you. In short, do you want to see `5` and `8`? Or do you want `13`? Or do you want `5`, `+` and `8` (all separately).

Comment: What is your question actually?

Comment: The result should be 5 and 8

Comment: subtract '0' from the numerical character to get the digit value.

Comment: The Problem is if i give it out like that it is 53 and 56

Answer (score 0):

use

`number[indexNumber] = calculation.charAt(iNumber) - '0';`

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Digit 0 has an ASCII value of 48. The range of ASCII value for 0-9 digits is from 48-57. So, whenever you extract a character, let's say '5', you store 53 instead of 5 in the array. So try to use the below code modification where you subtract character '0':

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int iNumber = 0;    int indexNumber = 0;


    String calculation = "5+8";
    int lengthCalculation = calculation.length();
    int[] number= new int[lengthCalculation/2+1];


    while(iNumber < lengthCalculation) {

        number[indexNumber] = calculation.charAt(iNumber)-'0'; //modified

            iNumber+=2;
            indexNumber++;
    }

    for(int q : number) {
        System.out.println(q);         }
}
```

Comment: Thx

Is it also posible to get the result 5, +, 8 somehow?
Because if i try it I get 5, -5, 8
Just wandering

Comment: See, the ASCII value for character '+' is 43. What you can do is reconvert 43 back to character in the following way: ```char x = (char) number[indexNumber]```.